# Binary '[': no operator found which takes a left-hand operand of type const Stack<int>

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have made a stack implementation (with singly linked list, also implemented by me) and when trying to overload "<<" operator for display purposes I came across this issue.

Here is my stack:

```
template <class T>
class Stack
{
    public:
        LinkedList<T> stack;
        int Length;

        Stack() {
            Length = 0;
        }

        void Push(const T value) {
            stack.Add(value);
            Length = stack.Length;
        }

        T Pop() {
            T value = stack[0];
            stack.Delete(0);
            Length = stack.Length;
            return value;
        }

        T operator[](const int index) {
            return stack[index];
        }

        friend std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& os, const Stack<T>& s) { //const here causes error
            for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
                os << s[i] << " ";
            return os;
        }
};
```

Indexing operator `[]` works fine I ran following code in main to test the stack:

```
Stack<int> stack;
stack.Push(10);
stack.Push(5);
stack.Push(11);
std::cout << stack[1] << std::endl; // prints 5 as expected
```

But when trying to print whole contents of stack using `std::cout << stack;` it gives me the error mentioned in the title. Removing `const` keyword from operator overloading fixes this issue, but as I know its not a good practice to pass objects which are not supposed to be mutable without `const` keyword.

How can I make the code work without removing `const` keyword?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator[]` is non-const which is why the compiler complains.

You can add a `const` overload to make i work:

```
T operator[](const int index) const {
    return stack[index];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Typically there should be two overloads for element access. One for a `const` instance that returns a constant reference:

```
    const T& operator[](const int index) const {
        return stack[index];           // ^^ -----------
    }
```

And one that returns a reference:

```
    T& operator[](const int index) {
        return stack[index];
    }
```

Wheter you provide the one returning a non-const reference is up to you, but you got the error because you have no `operator[]` for a `const Stack`.

PS: Note that the `const` on the paramter is not part of the method signature, but only has meaning inside the method. You could declare the method as `T& operator[](int index)` and it would be the same method. The `const` here only prevents you to modify `index` inside the method.